# bundle.js file gets deleted after file is already inside the cache on pwa

Tags: android, google-chrome, heroku, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

When i push my pwa to Heroku after some "close and reopen" the app, the bundle.js gets deleted from the cache storage inside the browser. So when i open the app it only shows a white screen. It only happens on Android with chrome.

my service worker:

```
CACHENAME = '2020-02-29 23:48:15.963115'
const CACHEASSETS = [
'./index.html',
'./main.css',
'./bundle.js',
'./sw.js',
'./manifest.json',
'./images',
'./static.json',
'./images/icons',
'./images/icons/icon-384x384.png',
'./images/icons/icon-96x96.png',
'./images/icons/icon-144x144.png',
'./images/icons/icon-72x72.png',
'./images/icons/icon-192x192.png',
'./images/icons/icon-128x128.png',
'./images/icons/icon-152x152.png',
'./images/icons/icon-512x512.png',
 './',
'./home',]
self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
    console.log('The service worker is being installed.');
    e.waitUntil(
      caches
      .open(CACHENAME)
      .then(cache => {
        console.log("Service Worker: Caching Files");
        cache.addAll(CACHEASSETS);
      })
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
      );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', (e) =>{
  console.log("Service Worker: Activated");
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames =>{
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cache =>{
          if(cache !== CACHENAME){
            console.log("Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache",cache);
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      )
    })
  )
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  console.log("Service Worker: Fetching", e);
  if(e.request.clone().method === 'GET'){
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then((cachedResponse) =>{
        return cachedResponse;
      })
    )
  }
});
```

Here is the app: https://mysterious-anchorage-81982.herokuapp.com/

Test enviroment: Chrome 80.0.3987.117 on Android 9.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write files to Heroku's filesystem? That won't work as expected, as that filesystem is ephemeral. Anything you write to it can be lost at any time, and _will_ be lost daily.

Comment: No, i mean the cache storage inside the browser, i don't write files to Herokus filesystem.

Comment: It seems that this problem only occurs on my phone. Maybe its because i have a custom rom. Idk.

Comment: @Samhamsam did you manage to figure this out? Facing the exact same issue (only appears since Chrome 80)

Comment: @SuparnaGharpure Nop, no solution yet.